# PHPMAILER, IsHTML already set to true

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

The isHTML is already set to True. But it doesnt work in the email i receive. I just get the sample html from a tutorial.

```
  <?php
    require("phpmailertest/class.phpmailer.php");
    $x=$_SESSION['items'];
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->IsSMTP(); // set mailer to use SMTP
        // $mail->SMTPDebug  = 2; 
        $mail->From = "benedictpayot@gmail.com";
        $mail->FromName = "BravoTech Solutions";
        $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // specif smtp server
        $mail->SMTPSecure= "ssl"; // Used instead of TLS when only POP mail is selected
        $mail->Port = 465; // Used instead of 587 when only POP mail is selected
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Username = "benedictpayot@gmail.com"; // SMTP username
        $mail->Password = "Ichthys030313!"; // SMTP password
        $mail->AddAddress($_SESSION['email_address']);
        $mail->IsHTML(true); 

        $mail->Subject  = "Mail Test";

        $mail->Body = '<html><body>';
        $mail->Body = '<table style="border-color: #eee;"';
        $mail->Body = '<tr>
                            <td>JALOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
                            <td>OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
                        <tr>
                            <td>BENEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEDICT
                            <td>PAYOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOT
                    </table>';

        $mail->WordWrap = 50;

        if(!$mail->Send()) {

        echo 'Message was not sent.';
            session_destroy();
        echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;

        } else {

        echo 'Message has been sent.';

        }
    ?>
```

Comment: You need to set $mail->MsgHTML not $mail->Body

Answer (score 1):

You can set `Body` (and `AltBody`) manually to any value you like. `msgHTML()` is a convenience function to set moth of them and optionally apply an html to text conversion to generate your plain text version. It also sets `isHTML`, rewrites image URLs and various other things - but you don't have to use it.

In your code you're saying:

```
$mail->Body = '<html><body>';
$mail->Body = '<table style="border-color: #eee;"';
$mail->Body = '<tr>...
```

Which should be:

```
$mail->Body = '<html><body>';
$mail->Body .= '<table style="border-color: #eee;"';
$mail->Body .= '<tr>...
```

otherwise you're just overwriting the contents of `Body` each time.

You should base your code on [the gmail example bundled with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps) - it looks like you are using an old one from somewhere else.

Comment: thanks for this. it is already working. My problem now is <table style="border-color: #eee;"> isnt working.

Comment: You need to be more specific than "isn't working", and if you have a different question (perhaps about CSS in email), you should probably ask a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure (correct me if I'm wrong) but I was always setting body like this:

```
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
```

Comment: Not necessarily - see my answer.

Comment: He said he gets message from the tutorial - but in this case the last $mail->Body should be used and it is pretty his :)